# Open source web service testing tools comparision matrix

Tags: soapui, web-service

Can any one help me out to get web service testing tool comaparison matrix  for soapUI, webInject, and TestMaker6 ?

Comment: What elements do you want to compare? What decision are you trying to make and why do you think a comparison matrix is useful?

Comment: Agree with Chris - a comparison is meaningless unless it allows you to answer the right question. We don't have any idea what you're hoping to accomplish with the tools.